# Twitter Connection hang after hours of streaming - Streaming API

Tags: twitter

Currently I am working with Streaming API (https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json).

After connection successful, i will record all the tweet from server into database. The problem only occurs after several hours or days of running without issue, and then no more tweets can be retrieved. If I restart the client, processing resumes as normal and everything runs fine until the next hang.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you could restart the service at certain interval, let say every 3 hours so it will stay connected and minimize the issue.

Comment: it could be a good alternative, but i still looking for a better solution..thx :)